# Where can i find a bootable ssd diagnostics tool?

Tags: ssd, bootable-media, diagnostic

I have a laptop, which has a Micron 128GB SSD.
I have a feeling that it is defective, but I don't know for sure. I need a bootable SSD diagnostics tool to verify this.

Where can I find a bootable SSD diagnostics tool?

---

There is one tool but that's only for lenovo systems it is called [Lenovo Diagnostic tool](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?&DocID=DS025448)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to check the health status : http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html

Or here is another program, though I never used it : http://ssd-life.com/eng/SSDLife-Freeware.html

Comment: crystalmark requires win32 to run, as such is not a valid answer for this question.

Answer (score 2):

Check out https://www.smartmontools.org.
Bootable using a Live USB/CD.

Comment: It is better to write more information not just a link

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this product. I recently used this to determine that an SSD was failing...

[Hard Disk Sentinel DOS by H.D.S. Hungary - Review and download](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/download/Hard_Disk_Sentinel_DOS_65568_p/)

Comment: that App was Kinda useless. I have a Lenovo laptop and i used a dos tool called, Lenovo diagnostic tool, and with it, it found out that my SSD indeed was defective.

Comment: @blade19899: The community bot popped this question up again.  Since you determined that the drive was defective, can you post an answer and accept it so people will know this doesn't still need to be solved?  Thanks.

Comment: I just tried HDS. Works ok, however their dos installer does not. I had to use rufus to get things rolling.