# What does the health status percentage represent in CrystalDiskInfo?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, diagnostic

I wonder what the health status percentage represents in [CrystalDiskInfo](https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/):

100%:

[image]

99%:

[image]

91%:

[image]

Absent:

[image]

I use CrystalDiskInfo on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: This HDD diagnostic utility is an solid source of information about the health & SMART status of your mechanical hard drive, @Franck! However, keep in mind that it's advisable to use the HDD manufacturer's diagnostic tool as well to monitor these stats. 
As for your SSDs, I'd recommend you use a [specific diagnostic utility](http://superuser.com/questions/512249/where-can-i-find-a-bootable-ssd-diagnostics-tool) as it would give you more accurate results about the SMART data. There are specific health-monitoring software for the different kind of hardware. Hope this helped! Good luck! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The health status percentage for SSD is intended to show the **remaining life** while in implementation it is just the calibrated percentage of a reference smart attribute chosen by CrystalDiskInfo (see [official manual](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/manual-en/HealthStatus.html)) which is specific to the SSD brand.

Supporting evidence:
Both 2nd and 3rd SSD from Crucial show percentage of 0xAD attribute. 1st SSD from Samsung shows 0xB3, while it should have been 0xB1, or a weighted sum of the two.

From [Samsung SSD White Paper](http://web.archive.org/web/20140311153329/http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/us/html/about/whitepaper07.html):

> ID #177 Wear Leveling Count
> This attribute represents the number of media program and erase operations (the number of times a block has been erased). **This value is directly related to the lifetime of the SSD.** The raw value of this attribute shows the total count of P/E Cycles.
>
> ID #179 Used Reserved Block Count (total)
> This attribute represents the number of reserved blocks that have been used as a result of a read, program or erase failure. This value is related to attribute 5 (Reallocated Sector Count) and will vary based on SSD density.